# Handling forms in a mutli-threading application?

Tags: multithreading, forms, messagebox

I have a pretty odd problem here. I have a multi-threaded program, one thread is for the user interface, and one thread initializes all of the components for the rest of the program. When I start the initializing thread, the user interface thread displays a form (over the main form) with a progress bar to show the user that something is happening (this is why the initializing thread is a separate thread, if it were done on the main thread, this form would never update and it would look like the program is crashed). At certain points in the initializing thread, the program may need to ask for user input; typically this is done by showing a message box. It is also important to note that the target PC has no keyboard or mouse, only a touchscreen interface.
Now here is the problem: if I put up a message box from inside the initializing thread, the main form is not the parent. What this means is if the user clicks outside of the message box, the message box goes behind the main form and the program is held up until the user connects a keyboard, and refocuses the message box to select an answer. 
I have tried all sorts of ways to get around this. I have tried making the main form the parent, but I get cross threading errors. I have tried making the initializing thread invoke the main thread, but then initialization continues and I can't feed back the result of the user input. I have made a special message box that is always on top, but this prevents errors from displaying (if an error occurs on a third thread). My final idea would probably work, but it is cumbersome and probably not the right solution. This would require me to make progress points for all of the initializing steps, as each step finishes, I would mark it as finished. Then if the initializing thread encounters a question it ends, the main thread asks the question, then restarts the initializing thread skipping all of the stuff that has already been initialized, and providing the .
I am out of ideas. How can I make my initializing thread pause and wait for feedback while my main thread is displaying the message box and provides this feedback?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: One solution could be to include paragraphs in your question ...

Comment: If this is Windows Forms, look into [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Also look into BackgroundWorker. It is specifically built for the purpose.

Comment: This happens because you display the message box with code that runs on a worker thread.  The message box window doesn't have an owner so can readily disappear behind another window.  Display it on the UI thread instead, use Contro.Invoke()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had already tried invoking the control, the problem was that you can't create a messagebox object (or at least that I don't know how and could not find any way to do so). The background worker would have also been a good solution, but the same problem of passing a message box occurs. I did find a way around this though, so I have posted it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, invoking the control ended up being the solution, however it was slightly more complicated than that. Since a messagebox object cannot be used outside of showing it, I could not create a messagebox to pass to the delegate. The solution to this was to create a messageboxproperties class that has all of the information needed to show a messagebox (parent, text, caption, icon, buttons). Then I pass an instance of this class to the delegate and have the delegate create/show the messagebox. This lets me pass any messagebox information and display it on any form, on the correct thread. It would still be nice if there was a way to pass the messagebox, but this works for now. Thanks for all the input!